# Howto use django regular inheritance in models and forms

Tags: python, django

How to define helpers to the `Class Event` so I can integrate them to `EventForm` and use them in `event_new(request)`.
The 'helpers' should be used in forms, views, templates but not go into the database. It's about showing existing events and autogenerate new events due to various aspects

```
models.py

class Event_helper(object):
   number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Event(Event_helper, models.Model):
   event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

```
forms.py

class EventForm(forms.Event):
    class Meta:
        model = Event 
        fields = ('event_date', 'number')
```

```
views.py

def event_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            ... generate events ...
            event.save()
```

Comment: You don't want to store the number in the db, that is only doable if there is a way to calculate it on the fly. What does number stands for?

Comment: In this case for the amount of events.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest solution I could find was without proper inheritance. But it is possible to make two different requests in views

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
   event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    number = forms.IntegerField(initial = 1)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('event_date',)
```

views.py

```
def event_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            number = int(request.POST['number'])
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            print(number)
            print(event)  
            ... generate events ...
            event.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use class [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/#term-property) that way you can use it in forms, views, templates but it does not go into the database.

```py
    class Event(models.Model):
        event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)

        @property
        def number(self):
            return `some value that you calculated`
```

```py
    class EventForm(ModelForm):
        number = forms.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            model = Event 
            fields = ('event_date',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = kwargs.get("instance", None)
            if instance:
                kwargs["initial"] = {"number": `some initial value you want`, }
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
    def event_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = EventForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                event = form.save(commit=False)
                ... generate events ...
                ... use event.number in the way you want...
                event.save()
```

Comment: in view: AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'number' and in forms: a Explicit return in __init__ Python(return-in-init)

Comment: @schasoli you are right, init does not have a return, edited the answer. If you define the number as a property you can use it as event.number, if you define it as a model function then you should call it as event.number()

Comment: the property solution works with a hardcoded return in `def number(self)`, but self has no value to calculate with.

Comment: and `kwargs["initial"] = {"number": `some initial value you want`, }` passes no argument to the new form. It looks like `number`is not part of the form

Comment: You need to add it as a field: number = forms.IntegerField()

Comment: How do you display the form? Or what makes you think even after adding the field that it is not there?

Comment: the field shows ` {{ form.number}}`,  but the initial value is not used and no value is comming back.

Comment: if I use `number = request.POST['number']` in views a `number = forms.IntegerField()` in forms is enough. No `number` in models what so ever. It feels somehow wrong, but I have the number to count with.